# Should I move the value out of an optional or move the whole optional?

Tags: c++, c++17, move, stdoptional

Is there an effective difference between `std::move(*optional)` and `*std::move(optional)`? Which one is preferable?

Full example:

```
#include <optional>
#include <vector>

void foo()
{
    std::optional<std::vector<int>> ov = std::vector<int>{};
    std::vector<int> v;
    v = std::move(*ov);
}

void bar()
{
    std::optional<std::vector<int>> ov = std::vector<int>{};
    std::vector<int> v;
    v = *std::move(ov);
}
```

Comment: Both are functionally equivalent, so I guess it depends on personal style.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They do the same thing.

In `v = std::move(*ov);`, `*ov` is a `std::vector<int>&` so `std::move(*ov)` gives you a `std::vector<int>&&` that you are trying to assign to `v`.

In `v = *std::move(ov);` `ov` is a `std::optional<std::vector<int>>` so `std::move(ov)` gives you a `std::optional<std::vector<int>>&&` and calling `*` on that calls `constexpr T&& operator*() && noexcept;` so you again have a `std::vector<int>&&` that you are trying to assign to `v`

Personally I prefer `v = std::move(*ov);` as `v = *std::move(ov);` makes me go: "Hmm, I am dereferencing, do I have an lvalue like most dereferences give or do I really have an rvalue?" and I would rather not have to ask myself that.